# No mouse in Vim inside nested screen sessions

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

For many reasons, I often work with nested [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) sessions. But Vim, running in a nested screen instance, doesn't seem to catch any mouse info. I've tried `:set mouse=a` and `:set ttymouse=xterm2`, the tricks that normally get Vim recognizing the mouse, to no avail. Any pointers? Or...cursors? Help please!

Comment: One pointer: stop using your mouse.

Comment: @romainl I'm developing web applications -- for the same reason it's a pain to switch from keyboard to mouse constantly, same goes for the inverse

Comment: That's my job too and I don't use the mouse in Vim and as little as possible elsewhere. Using the mouse is unavoidable when I test a functionality in the browser but I don't see it as a problem. The fact is that, in Vim, the mouse is seriously limited compared to other movement/selection/scrolling methods, hence my comment. Like me, you probably spend most of your time in Vim and only a few moments in mouse land: crippling your workhorse just because of those few moments in mouse land doesn't seem to be the most sensible choice. But you are free to make it, of course.

Comment: Anyway, what does `$ echo $TERM` say in all those nested screen sessions?

Answer (score 2):

Mouse is not supported in `screen`.  You can try `tmux` with those conf:

```
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
```